# cakephp3 email message has missing link

Tags: html, cakephp-3.x

I have an email template for cakephp

```
    <span style="padding:8px 12px 8px 12px;background:#3030a7;border-radius:4px">
        <?= $this->Html->link("DOWNLOAD APP", 
                'itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.example.com/40843.plist', ['style'=>'color:white']) ?>
    </span>
```

But the weird thing is when I run the program, this is what I get from the google mail

```
<span style="padding:8px 12px 8px 12px;background:#3030a7;border-radius:4px">
        <a style="color:white">DOWNLOAD APP</a>        
    </span>
```

As you notice, the all important attribute 'href' is missing. Is it because the email class did not support it? What am I missing?

Comment: Does Yahoo mail show the same?

Comment: yahoo shows, google does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

direct link to download app doesn't work at some email service provider.

so I usually add a regular link like "http://example.com/link-to-download-the-app" and make a web page for the link and then when the user click the link, the user is yours.